# How to show google play in-app review API in android?

Tags: android

I use [Google Play In-App Review API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) in my app:

```
val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
request.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
    if (request.isSuccessful) {
        val reviewInfo = request.result
        val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
        flow.addOnCompleteListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for review", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, request.exception!!.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

When I run this code for the first time, the Google play dialog shows up and the user can give stars and comments. But when I run again this code, nothing showing up, and just a toast showing: **Thanks for review**.

How am I show again that dialog?

Answer (score 2):

The API has a limitation on how many times / how often the review dialog is shown. This is so you don't spam your users asking for a review too often. The limits are not public and they can change at any time.
The OnCompleteListener will be triggered either way even if the dialog never shows, so I would not advise showing a toast there assuming the user reviewed the app.